# jQuery SlidesJS - Can't restart animation after clicking on navigation

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am using the new slideJS V3.0 but I can't seem to make the slide animation restart after it has been paused by clicking on the navigation.  I saw someone who said they made it work with the pagination, so I tried using that, to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I'm using (currently trying to just get it to work even with pagination)

```
<script>

$(function() {

  $('#slides').slidesjs({

    width: 905,
    height: 310,
     navigation: false,
  play: {
    auto: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    effect: 'fade',
    restartDelay: 1500
  },
  pagination: {
    effect: 'fade',
    play: {          
      restartDelay: 1500
    }
  },
  effect: {
    fade: {
       speed: 1500
    },       
    crossfade: true
  }

  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done without modifying the plugin (using SlideJS 3.0).
Just add the following complete callback in your options:

```
$('#slides').slidesjs({
    callback: {
        complete: function(number) {
            var pluginInstance = $('#slides').data('plugin_slidesjs');

            setTimeout(function() {
                pluginInstance.play(true);
            }, pluginInstance.options.play.interval);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just saw this now, unfortunately we had to go with another solution, but I wish I had tried this earlier.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In your jquery.slides.js file do a search for _this.stop(true);

It shows about 3-4 times, next & previous click.. and you will also see it showing for paginationLink.click

The problem i was having was the slider was stop sliding after click either previous, next or pagination. I needed the slider to restart.. so what i did was add a setTimeout to play()

```
_this.stop(true);

setTimeout(function ()
{ _this.play(true) }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today.

Here's how to solve it: in jquery.sldes.js file go to line 184 and change it to be like this

```
return _this.goto(($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item") * 1) + 1) && _this.play();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I tried this but if you click on the active slide it won´t restart the animation, but if you click on any other slide works ok. Do you know how to fix the click on the same slide ?

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/cujeqekate
older version or new version:

```js
$(function($) {
  var interval = 4000;
  var st = 0;
  var $slides = $('#slides');
  $slides.slidesjs({
    width: 800,
    height: 450,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: interval,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    callback: {
      start: function(number){
        if ( $slides.find('.slidesjs-play').is(':visible')) {
          clearTimeout(st);
          st = setTimeout(function() {
             $slides.find('.slidesjs-play').click();
          }, interval);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```